# How can I create a script tag to render my Next.js application?

Tags: javascript, next.js, build, bundle

I have to render my whole nextjs application in a script tag
I made a chatbot, now if I give a script tag to my client, and if it keeps it in his code, it renders my chatbot, how do I make a script tag out of my nextjs application

I checked online that I have to first build my application with `next build` then I have to export my application
I did all but now I don't know what file I have to give to the script tag as there are so many files generated with this build

I tried to render a page[hash].js file from .next/static/chunks but it didn't seem to work
I also saw the request to that in the network tab and it is 200 ok.
I also checked the console (no error or warning)
but still, it didn't seem to work

Comment: You can use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) to show your NextJS webapp into another site.

Comment: I'd recommend not using next. Use react on it's own?